# OpenAI_API chat returning null

Tags: c#, asynchronous, openai-api

I'm attempting to stream the results from a call to ChatGPT using the [OpenAI_API](https://github.com/OkGoDoIt/OpenAI-API-dotnet) library.

```
public async IAsyncEnumerable<string> Stream(string prompt) {
    var chat = api.Chat.CreateConversation(new ChatRequest() {
        Model = this.LanguageModel,
        Temperature = 0.1,
        MaxTokens = 50
    });
    chat.AppendUserInput(prompt);
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Querying with prompt: {0}", prompt));

    int i = 0;
    await foreach (var resp in chat.StreamResponseEnumerableFromChatbotAsync()) {
        Console.WriteLine(i++);
        Console.WriteLine(chat.MostResentAPIResult);
        yield return resp;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Last");
    Console.WriteLine(chat.MostResentAPIResult);
}
```

The [documentation](https://chat.StreamResponseEnumerableFromChatbotAsync) shows this usage:

```
var chat = api.Chat.CreateConversation();
chat.AppendUserInput("How to make a hamburger?");

await foreach (var res in chat.StreamResponseEnumerableFromChatbotAsync())
{
    Console.Write(res);
}
```

Unfortunately, when I test my implementation (without all the console logging) it returns an empty string.

```
public async Task IntegrationTestPromptStream() {
    IConversation conv = new OpenAIConversation(OpenAI_API.Models.Model.GPT4);
    var response = conv.Stream("Repeat back this sentence \"This is a multi word example that should chunk\"");
    var chunks = new List<string>();
    await foreach (var chunk in response) {
        chunks.Append(chunk);
    }

    Assert.That(
        String.Join(" ", chunks),
        Is.EqualTo("This is a multi word example that should chunk"),
        "Didn't receive expected response from OpenAI chat");
}
```

I added the console logging statements to work out what was being invoked and this is the output

```
Querying with prompt: Repeat back this sentence "This is a multi word example that should chunk"
0

NUnit Adapter 4.1.0.0: Test execution complete
```

If I attach the debugger and attempt to examine `chat.MostResentAPIResult` [sic], I can see an object, but notably the `.ToString()` method throws a null reference exception.

[image]

Finally, if I just keep hte index counter in but remove the statements to output the last response, I get this

```
Querying with prompt: Repeat back this sentence "This is a multi word example that should chunk"
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
Last
```

So It'll iterate through empty strings all day long but attempting to look at the response returns a null or a NullReferenceException.

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried `chunks.Add(chunk);` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;


List<string> strings = new List<string>();

void OutputAdd()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Output for Add Mehtod ...");


    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        strings.Add($"Testing using Add {i}");
    }

    foreach (var line in strings)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(line);
    }
}

void OutputAppend()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Output for Append Mehtod ...");


    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        strings.Append($"Testing using Append {i}");
    }

    foreach (var line in strings)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(line);
    }
}

void OutputAppendFixed()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Output for Append Fixed Mehtod ...");


    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        strings = strings.Append($"Testing using Append with added code {i}").ToList();
    }

    foreach (var line in strings)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(line);
    }
}

OutputAdd();

OutputAppend();

OutputAppendFixed();
```

If you run this, you'll see that `OutputAppend()` will only show what was added from `OutputAdd()`. Then when `OutputAppendFixed()` runs it will add using the `Append` method. This has to do with `Append` returning an `IEnumerable<T>`.

The `Add` modifies the original data while `Append` returns a new array without modifying the original data.